# AJAX doesn't get data from PHP file with Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying post data to PHP file but i can't receive any data from PHP file. Let me add codes.
This is my jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(function () {
$('a[class="some-class"]').click(function(){

   var somedata = $(this).attr("id");

   $.ajax({
      url: "foo.php", 
      type: "POST",
      data: "id=" + somedata,

      success: function(){
          $("#someid").html();
      },
      error:function(){
          alert("AJAX request was a failure");
      }
    });
    });
    });
});
```

This is my PHP file:

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['id'];

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','somedatabase');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"database");
$sql="SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE id = '".$data."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

 echo $row['info'];

 }

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

This what i have in HTML file:

```
<p id="someid"></p>

<a href="#page2" class="some-class" id="1">Data1</a>
<a href="#page2" class="some-class" id="2">Data2</a>
```

Note: This website is horizontal scrolling and shouldn't be refreshed. When i'm clicking links (like Data1) it's going to another page without getting data from PHP file

Comment: This is a POST request -.- do not use data: "id=" + somedata, but something like id:somedata

Comment: you need to add `?` at ur url after `.php` `url: "foo.php?",`

Comment: any solutions presented help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems:

1. You are not using the data as mentioned in the other answers:
   `success: function(data){
         $("#someid").html(data);
     },`
2. You are not cancelling the default click action so your link will be followed:
   `$('a[class="some-class"]').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       ...`;
3. As the id's are integers, you can use `data: "id=" + somedata,` although sending an object is safer in case `somedata` contains characters that need to be escaped:
   `data: {"id": somedata},`;
4. You have an sql injection problem. You should cast the variable to an integer or use a prepared statement:
   `$data = (int) $_POST['id'];`;
5. As also mentioned in another answer, you have two `$(document).ready()` functions, one wrapping the other. You only need one.

Comment: thank you! The only problem was forget to add 'data' to function and html. I want to ask another question for this, This function gets every data from PHP file but i want to take about 5 variable for each <p> How can i do that?

Comment: @KorhanYüzbaş That's really another question, but in short, you could return json containing whatever you need and parse / use that in the `success()` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function(){
          $("#someid").html();
      },
```

should be:

```
success: function(data){
          $("#someid").html(data);
      },
```

Comment: thank you so much it's working now!
I want to ask another question for this,
This function gets every data from PHP file but i want to take about 5 variable for each <p>
How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should add parameter in success

```
success: function(data){ //Added data parameter
      console.log(data);
      $("#someid").html(data);
  },
```

The data get the values what you echo in PHP end.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
  success: function(data){
      $("#someid").html(data);
  },
```

and you have two document ready, so get rid of:

```
$(document).ready(function () { ...

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data: "id=" + somedata,
```

Change it to:

```
data: { id : somedata }
```

Comment: A querystring is perfectly valid for `data`

Comment: `somedata` could be a not valid part of a querystring, so this solution would fix this problem.